# Evaluation of a series by hand

Tags: summation

I want to evaluate the series
$$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{nx^n}{(1+x)^{n+1}}$$
I don't know how to do this by hand, but Mathematica tells me that the answer is:
$$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{nx^n}{(1+x)^{n+1}}=x$$

and this is indeed the answer I want.
However, I still want to know how to do this by hand.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**HINT**

We have that

$$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{nx^n}{(1+x)^{n+1}}=\frac1{1+x}\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}n\left(\frac{x}{1+x}\right)^n$$

then recall that

$$\sum_{k=0}^\infty kr^{k}=\frac{r}{(1-r)^2}\;\;,\;\;|r|<1$$

Comment: You are too fast for the old man ! I was finishing typing the same when your answer came in. $\to +1$

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici I'm sorry Claude, in that case you should show also your answer! Repetita iuvant :)

Comment: Don't be sorry for anything ! You did it very well, that is it ! Cheers, my friend (if I may).

Comment: Gimusi.Presque comme toujours.Formidable.

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici I’m honored if I may be your friend! Thanks

Comment: @PeterSzilas You always are too kind with me! Bye